# Extracting transport stream h264 informations?

Tags: stream, structure, h.264, frames, transport

I need to extract some informations abour a ts file containing h264 video.
I want to know where the I frames are.
I can't find somethong on the net which explain the ts h264 structure. So if someone have a link ...

I have already done it with a stream containing a mpeg2 video (I found  this page : http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/mpeghdrs.html)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A question really for superuser.com.

If you want just location of I pictures and some other details use ffprobe [comes with ffmpeg]

```
 ffprobe -show_frames inputfile
```

will give details of picture type, size etc.